# device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: linux, usb, linux-kernel

I have problem with USB ports on MSI WIND laptop.

I have FC17 installed and USB printer sometimes not responds. If I replug a printer in USB port - it's working. Tried to change USB cable and printer also, it doesn't matter. Tried another Linux distribution - didn't help. Tried to use another USB ports at laptop - same error.

when the printer is not working there are some errors in /var/log/messages:

```
Dec 12 14:01:50 localhost kernel: [319505.935168] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 64 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:50 localhost kernel: [319506.345172] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:51 localhost kernel: [319506.461123] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 65 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:51 localhost kernel: [319506.871166] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 65, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:51 localhost kernel: [319507.021161] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 66 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:51 localhost kernel: [319507.135162] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:51 localhost kernel: [319507.362161] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:52 localhost kernel: [319507.578182] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 67 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:52 localhost kernel: [319507.692174] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:52 localhost kernel: [319507.920131] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:52 localhost kernel: [319508.136164] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 68 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:53 localhost kernel: [319508.546169] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 68, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:53 localhost kernel: [319508.662176] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 69 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:53 localhost kernel: [319509.072165] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 69, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:58 localhost kernel: [319514.353165] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 70 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:59 localhost kernel: [319514.466162] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:59 localhost kernel: [319514.693162] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:59 localhost kernel: [319514.909170] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 71 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:01:59 localhost kernel: [319515.023156] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:01:59 localhost kernel: [319515.251130] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:00 localhost kernel: [319515.467165] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 72 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:00 localhost kernel: [319515.877164] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 72, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:00 localhost kernel: [319515.992182] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 73 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:00 localhost kernel: [319516.402171] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 73, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:01 localhost kernel: [319516.552177] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 74 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:01 localhost kernel: [319516.666157] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:01 localhost kernel: [319516.893165] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:01 localhost kernel: [319517.109176] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 75 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:01 localhost kernel: [319517.222162] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:02 localhost kernel: [319517.450164] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:02 localhost kernel: [319517.666159] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 76 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:02 localhost kernel: [319518.076164] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 76, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:02 localhost kernel: [319518.191184] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 77 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:03 localhost kernel: [319518.601159] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 77, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:08 localhost kernel: [319523.882165] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 78 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:08 localhost kernel: [319523.996164] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:08 localhost kernel: [319524.224160] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:09 localhost kernel: [319524.440115] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 79 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:09 localhost kernel: [319524.554143] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:09 localhost kernel: [319524.782131] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:09 localhost kernel: [319524.998151] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 80 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:10 localhost kernel: [319525.408135] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 80, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:10 localhost kernel: [319525.524139] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 81 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:10 localhost kernel: [319525.934110] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 81, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:10 localhost kernel: [319526.084163] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 82 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:10 localhost kernel: [319526.198163] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:11 localhost kernel: [319526.426163] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:11 localhost kernel: [319526.642173] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 83 using uhci_hcd
Dec 12 14:02:11 localhost kernel: [319526.756145] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:11 localhost kernel: [319526.984162] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 12 14:02:15 localhost kernel: [319530.420111] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
```

Comment: a) Fedora 17 is long out of support. b) This is clearly [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I did try recent Fedora, didn't help. And one more thing - there were no problems when laptop runned Windows XP